# Wordpress Form Manager - Email issues

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

When a form was submitted, user didn't receive the email notification.

what's the problem should be?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-form-manager/

Can any one please help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What kind of host are you using? Does it support SMTP?

Comment: I am trying to connect from localhost. In php.ini file, SMTP = localhost, smtp_port = 25 and sendmail_from = raghupathy0123@gmail.com. Is the settings are correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an SMTP server. Your SMTP values in the php.ini should redirect to a valid SMTP server.

This link might help you use Gmail's SMTP
http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/